# Android Exception :- android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-resources, android-inflate

While inflating Appbarlayout in lower version android device I Received FileNotFoundException from one particular device on the same screen. Following file "ic_download_active.png" is not part of my application but why it is trying to fetch?

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_download_active.png from xml type anim resource ID #0x7f020000
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2817)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2772)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1113)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:165)
        at android.support.design.widget.ViewUtilsLollipop.setStateListAnimatorFromAttrs(ViewUtilsLollipop.java:50)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.<init>(AppBarLayout.java:183)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
```

My AppBarLayout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/userdata_item_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/f_tabbar_tab_prefered_height"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/items_delete_btn"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/user_items_delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity code android manifest :-

```
            android:name=".activity.MapsAppActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Styles :-

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"></style>
```

Comment: are you using androidx libraries in your build.gradle file?

Comment: no, I'm using android support library.

Comment: Try invalidate caches and restart and check that .png throughout your project, if you are using it anywhere remove it.